# Rollback changes to the commited update statements

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, commit, rollback, flashback

There are around 1500 records updated in my database and unfortunately, I had committed the changes.
I could remember that there is an option to rollback the changes in oracle 11g.

I am using Toad tool and I had run the below query

```
    FLASHBACK TABLE abc  TO TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '15' minute);
```

Got an alert message stating that "cannot flashback the table as the row movement is not enabled."

Can you please help me in implementing the command and rollback the committed changes on the 1500 records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable row movement for your table:

```
alter table abc enable row movement;
```

But I'd recommend making a backup of the current state of your table first before you perform any DML / DDL statements.